# Responsive image-buttons over slider

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a carousel-slider from Bootstrap 3.3.7 on my website, and I would like to add two images as nav buttons on it.

I would like to place these buttons a little bit covering my slider, and get slider vertically aligned to the buttons (buttons are higher), and get it still responsive. I am now so frustrated because of it doesn't work like I want to, so I decided to ask you for help.

I think the picture can imagine what I mean.

Thank you.[I think the picture can imagine what I mean.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkM3C.png)

Answer (score 0):

When making responsive web pages, add the following  element in all your web pages:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Also, In your case you can play with the width of the image, hope this helps.